# how to change a css class when all tabs are closed in ui.bootstrap.accordion

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

How can I change a css class when all the tabs in ui.bootstrap.accordion are closed,for instance if the tabs were closed because another tab triggered them to close, the ng-class expression won't run and won't change the icon.

This is the view

```
<uib-accordion>
            <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="item in portafolio | orderBy : 'order' " ng-click="item.opened=!item.opened">
                <uib-accordion-heading>
                    <i class="fa fa-lg" ng-class="(item.opened === true) ? 'fa-minus-circle':'fa-plus-circle'"></i>
                        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
                    <i class="pull-right fa fa-lg" ng-class="{'fa-caret-down': true === item.opened, 'fa-caret-right': false === item.opened}"></i>
                </uib-accordion-heading>
                <div ng-include="'modules/widgets/portafolio/tpl/'+item.type+'.html'"></div>
            </uib-accordion-group>
        </uib-accordion>
```

And in the controller I have this.

```
$scope.portfolio = [
  { type: 'Balance', order:1, name:'current balance', opened: false},
  { type: 'Credits', order:2, name:'Credits', opened: false},
  { type: 'Investments', order:3, name:'Investments', opened: false}
];
```

I tried to use the ng-class directive in order to evaluate if the item.opened was true or false,but when the tabs were closed because another tab closed them, the item.opened wont update.

Indeed, I've researched that with $watch I can "watch" for changes and run a function, I saw that when I click on one tab, a css class '.panel-open'is added ,but how can I watch that div element that the css class has been added in order to update the i class elements.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use a `$watch` that accepts a function and that function will test if all the panels are closed, can you post what you have done so far ?

Comment: Thanks bro, I've updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Well, you basically want to watch for any changes in your `portfolios` array, when all of the `opened` properties are `false`, trigger a value bound to `$scope` that will change a class, preferably using something like `ng-class` (this will also work using `ng-style`).

Because you watch an array, you should using `$watchCollection` instead of plain old `$watch`

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {
    return $scope.portfolio.every((item) => {
        return item.opened === false; 
    })
  }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      $scope.value = newValue;
})
```

`Array.prototype.every` will return true if all the items in an array return true on a predicate function, in this case, all of the `.opened` properties are false.

Then setup something like

```
ng-class="{'btn-primary': value, 'btn-success': !value}"
```

[Here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uQ3esaxaCuEnBgyP459d?p=preview)

- Your question was kind of hard to understand, comment if I didn't cover something.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro, much appreciated, I ended up using jQuery I don't know if it's a good approach, I attached a click listener to the tab element then with .each() I checked if the elements had the panel-open class and if they do, I removed the fa-plus-circle class if they don't I added the fa-minus-cirlce class,tbh I'm still learning angularJs

Comment: i preferred using `.every` to something like `.each` because `every` breaks when it find a value that doesn't return true in the function.
jquery is fine, but ui-bootstrap doesn't use it, the use case is also pretty simple, i really doubt you'll need that JUST for this one.
anyhow don't forget to upvote if you found this answer useful.